# Rails 3.1 Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm getting an intermittent Application Error on my Rails App and can't for the life of me see what's causing it. The App was working fine until about an hour ago!!

Here's my logs.....can anyone see what's wrong?

```
2012-06-07T16:09:59+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:09:59 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/pages-45be288bf1c354b73ecc4adeca059617.png HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/application-84db2ac3553aab7e2791e4b5ca93ebbf.js HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/support-64961f422b35d272aa96f67986f96d0d.png HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/users-c568f05664b07849a5fc6ce332fd41aa.png HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gent

2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/nav/settings-cca0ffa9e065cf27a2a6c2f86c13bd2b.png] fresh
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/settings-cca0ffa9e065cf27a2a6c2f86c13bd2b.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/CD-6a8afb79b7099999b2c433ea6c88556e.png HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/media-4d836bc533c824782f9e9c0d16b7eb27.png HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/Chart2-f56078de9116b920d1bdbbbd1bf1e30f.png HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla

2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/nav/maps-887a3c6fb5517ad187a552194719ea39.png] fresh
2012-06-07T16:10:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:00 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/maps-887a3c6fb5517ad187a552194719ea39.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:01+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:01 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/pages-45be288bf1c354b73ecc4adeca059617.png HTTP/1.1" 503 1085 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:01+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/Home-70b3adf79c12b22e54419a4e1b4ee31e.png] fresh
2012-06-07T16:10:01+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:01 +0000] "GET /assets/Home-70b3adf79c12b22e54419a4e1b4ee31e.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:01+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/nav/clipboard-9cc6dcc33d25e94a2e88df388916afec.png] fresh
2012-06-07T16:10:01+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 84.19.42.202 - - [07/Jun/2012:16:10:01 +0000] "GET /assets/nav/clipboard-9cc6dcc33d25e94a2e88df388916afec.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3260 "http://gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com
2012-06-07T16:10:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/assets/token-input-facebook-a6fe07057db378b23a567f6ceaab6a7b.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=19ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=2519
2012-06-07T16:10:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/assets/Tag-Blue-62e036781e85b8a0c324f08b3d06fbae.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=15ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=356
2012-06-07T16:10:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/assets/nav/settings-cca0ffa9e065cf27a2a6c2f86c13bd2b.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=6ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=783
2012-06-07T16:10:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/assets/nav/maps-887a3c6fb5517ad187a552194719ea39.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=29ms service=82ms status=200 bytes=3331
2012-06-07T16:10:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/assets/Home-70b3adf79c12b22e54419a4e1b4ee31e.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=11ms service=51ms status=200 bytes=773
2012-06-07T16:10:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gentle-lightning-5246.heroku.com/assets/nav/clipboard-9cc6dcc33d25e94a2e88df388916afec.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=43ms service=44ms status=200 bytes=3260
```

Comment: dont see an error in that set of logs..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku was down for a short time.  It seems to be getting back to normal for some apps.  http://status-old.heroku.com

Comment: Really!! Wow! I thought it was way more robust!

Comment: Yeah, this has happened to me a couple of times.  I'm now convinced that the ease of deployment is no longer worth the risk of downtime for my apps.  I'll be switching to Linode most likely.

Comment: Totally, i'm still demoing my work and it makes me look like I don't know what i'm doing.......I don't but that's another matter, haha!